# Resize sprites in an array no working

Tags: java, animation, libgdx

I have what I presume is a very basic problem. I am trying to do a basic animation using 7 sprites, 6 of which are are in a Sprite[] array.

Now I currently have it animating properly when I press the keys, besides flipping when going left but that's something for me to figure out later. For now I want to resize these sprites.

They are currently sized to 32x68. Here is my code:

```
jimRect = new Rectangle();

    jimRect.height = 96;
    jimRect.width = 48;
    jimRect.x = 800 / 2 - jimRect.getWidth();
    jimRect.y = 0;

    // Create our assets
    rock = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/img/rock.png"));
    gems = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/img/gems.png"));
    jim0 = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/img/jim0.png")));
    jim1 = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/img/jim1.png")));
    jim2 = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/img/jim2.png")));
    jim3 = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/img/jim3.png")));
    jim4 = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/img/jim4.png")));
    jim5 = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/img/jim5.png")));
    jim6 = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/img/jim6.png")));

    // Create animations
    sprites = new Sprite[] { jim1, jim2, jim3, jim4, jim5, jim6 };
    walkFrames = new Animation(ANIM_DURATION, sprites);
    stateTime = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < sprites.length - 1; i++){
        sprites[i].setSize(jimRect.getWidth(), jimRect.getHeight());
        System.out.println("Resized " + i + " sprites to " + jimRect.getWidth() + "x" + jimRect.getHeight());
    }
}
```

So basically I create a rectangle with the height of 96 and width of 48 to make Jim a little bigger, I then go through the process of creating my sprites and then adding them to the array (I know, texture regions with a split method would be better but it was causing problems and annoying me).

I then create my animation with the duration and the sprites array.

Now this part here in particular:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < sprites.length - 1; i++){
    sprites[i].setSize(jimRect.getWidth(), jimRect.getHeight());
    System.out.println("Resized " + i + " sprites to " + jimRect.getWidth() + "x" + jimRect.getHeight());
}
```

Why is this not working? I even added a super fancy console print so I could tell the loop was even initiating, that the array was being iterating through properly and that the width/height of my rectangle was what I put it as.

Comment: Punch me, it seems I have to do my resizing in the batch.draw method using the arguements batch.draw(currentFrame, x, y, width, height)

Answer (score 0):

If you draw your sprites like [this](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html#draw%28com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch%29):

```
sprite.setRegion(currentFrame);
sprite.draw();
```

Then your code should work. Only one thing though, this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sprites.length - 1; i++){
```

should be done like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sprites.length; i++){
```

You are missing the last sprite there.

If you are doing it like [this](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html#draw%28com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29):

```
batch.draw(currentFrame, x, y, width, height);
```

Then, indeed, setting the height and width inside that method works.